# Javascript jsPDF UTF-8 character problems

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have a problem

I am having utf-8 character problem when converting in jspdf

```
    window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
    applyPlugin(window.jsPDF);

    function downPdf () {
        let doc = new jsPDF()
        console.log('asd')
        const elementHTML = document.querySelector('#pdf')
        doc.html(elementHTML, {
            callback: function (doc) {
                // Save the PDF
                doc.save('sample-document.pdf')
            },
            x: 15,
            y: 15,
            width: 170, // target width in the PDF document
            windowWidth: 650 // window width in CSS pixels
        })
    }
```

no problem downloading and working

The only problem is that a few characters such as "ğ", "ş", "ı" have problems while converting.

Comment: What encoding is your source data?

Comment: you mean source code?

I don't quite understand what you mean, sorry

Comment: You're converting _something_ to PDF. What encoding is that something? The `ş` didn't come out of nowhere.

Comment: The server tells your browser what character encoding it's sending, and the browser believes it. You can look at the Network developer tool and look at the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KJ said, fonts need to be added, I chose to use the plugin called html2topdf to avoid dealing with it.

and I solved my problem in this way, there is no such problem in that library